# Angular 2: ngOnChanges fires when template renders

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When my template renders the function inside ngOnChanges fires one time, and then only when an @input changes. Is this the expected behaviour and how can I prevent it?

Child:

```
export class MobileMenuComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

@Input('test') dezeTest: string;

//declare menu
menu;

constructor() { 

    //define menu

    this.menu = {state: 'inactive'};

}

togglemenu() {

    var that = this;

    if (that.menu.state === 'inactive'){

        that.menu.state = 'active';

    }

    else {

        that.menu.state = 'inactive';

    }

}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {


    this.togglemenu();


}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour of ngOnChanges.

The ngOnChanges method will fire the first time because your properties have been checked, and subsequently fire when a property is updated. From the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html), you can see

> ngOnChanges is called right after the data-bound properties have been checked and before view and content children are checked if at least one of them has changed.

If you want to change it, you need to consider how you want to change it. That is not very clear from your question, but if you want to prevent the ngOnChanges from firing again, when a property is updated (I think that you want this because of your `toggleMenu()` you might consider using the `ngOnInit()` instead of `ngOnChanges()`. Alternatively, you can block the togglemenu(); after the first time.

```
 firstrun : boolean = true; // class variable
 ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges){
    if(firstrun){
      this.togglemenu();
      firstrun = false;
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, as hinted at earlier, another [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) might suit your needs better.

Comment: Thanks, the second one was the thing I was looking for. The story behind this question is that a user should push a button in one component and something needs to happen in the child component. Is there a better way to do that without ngOnChanges?

Comment: @Dirk You could use reactive extensions for this as well. You could create a subject somewhere which holds the state of the menu (subject of a boolean, true/false). When a button is pressed on a component - change the state of the subject. This will create an event which a subscriber can observe. (In your children, you can then observe this event, and handle the change appropriately)

Comment: Okay. So kinda like a HTTP request with a observable. Do you have something I can watch or read to learn more on the matter? Because it sounds like observables are the cleaner solution.

Comment: @Dirk take a look here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service That should help you on your way :-)

Comment: Thanks. This there btw a reason why I won't just do this? let that = this;

        `let menubutton = document.getElementById('menubutton')
        let clicks = Observable.fromEvent(menubutton, 'click')
        clicks.subscribe(click => {

            that.togglemenu();

        });`

Answer (score 3):

To expand on existing answers, and address a typing question raised in a comment at the same time:

The SimpleChange#firstChange field exists for this exact case.

Alternatively, because the value is set on your Component before ngOnChanges is called, you can also check if a field has changed, followed by if it's set:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: { myField: SimpleChange }) {
    if(changes.myField && this.myField){ 
        // do a thing only when 'myField' changes and is not nullish.
    }
    // Or, if you prefer: 
    if(changes.myField && changes.myField.firstChange){ 
        // Do a thing only on the first change of 'myField'.
        // WARNING! If you initialize the value within this class 
        // (e.g. in the constructor)  you can get null values for your first change
    }
}
```

Another little warning: If you were to use tools like WebStorm to rename 'myField' on your Component, the 'myField' of the ngOnChanges method parameters ({myField: SimpleChange }) will NOT be updated. Which can lead to some fun Component initialization errors.

Answer (score 1):

As Dylan Meeus suggested, its the normal behaviour.
but i would suggest a different solution, which takes advantage of the passed SimpleChange object. it contains a previousValue and a currentValue.. initially, the previousValue is not set.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/SimpleChange-class.html

```
ngOnChanges(changes : any){
   if(changes.menu.previousValue){
      this.togglemenu();
   }
}
```

additionally, take care about OnChanges, since it fires on every input param... (you might add some more in the future)

Comment: Also a good solution. But I'm running into trouble. When I try to acces keys of the changes var Typescript gives me a does not exits error. "Property 'menubutton' does not exist on type 'SimpleChanges'.
any" If I log changes to the console I see it has a menubutton property. What am I doing wrong?Edit: codes seems to run. Still would like to discard the TS error.

Comment: well i see, you can either create a custom definition of SimpleChanges or define it as any.

ngOnChanges(changes : any)

Comment: Or you can just use `changes["menubutton"].previousValue` instead of `changes.menubutton.previousValue`. There is also a method `isFirstChange()` in `SimpleChange` so you should rather use `changes["menubutton"].isFirstChange()`.